# Mixed-effect output of lmer showing more slopes than anticipated

Tags: r, interpretation, fixed-effects-model, lme4-nlme

My data consists of a numerical, continuous variable and 4 independent variables, plus two sources of random variation. I am running mixed-effects model in R with the `lmer()` function.

```
head(MM_Table2)
      Name                    Condition Channel EpochCountStd EpochCountDeviant ErpMinTime ErpMinVoltage ErpMinAv Frequency
380   AY11042016B1-Deci.EEG      HFMM     AF3           423               103        203          -1.2     -1.1      High
388 AvdP23052016B1-Deci.EEG      HFMM     AF3           410               101        144          -3.7     -3.2      High
397   EW20042016B1-Deci.EEG      HFMM     AF3           457               118        123          -2.6     -2.3      High
413  IG160312016B1-Deci.EEG      HFMM     AF3           435               105        214          -2.2     -1.6      High
422  IJB18042016B1-Deci.EEG      HFMM     AF3           408               110        121          -1.3     -1.1      High
439   MC31032016B1-Deci.EEG      HFMM     AF3           438               101        116          -4.0     -3.3      High
   Hemisphere     Region      Lexicality Subject    Block    Hemisphere.Centered Region.Centered Lexicality.Centered
380       Left AnterioFrontal       Word Subject08  -2.5                  -1              -2                   1
388       Left AnterioFrontal       Word Subject14  -2.5                  -1              -2                   1
397       Left AnterioFrontal       Word Subject12  -2.5                  -1              -2                   1
413       Left AnterioFrontal       Word Subject02  -2.5                  -1              -2                   1
422       Left AnterioFrontal       Word Subject10  -2.5                  -1              -2                   1
439       Left AnterioFrontal       Word Subject05  -2.5                  -1              -2                   1
          Frequency.Centered
380                  1
388                  1
397                  1
413                  1
422                  1
439                  1
```

I learned that it's best to recode your fixed effects with numbers that sum to zero. For example, one of my fixed effects is called `Lexicality`, and has two levels: `Word` and `PseudoWord`. I created a new column in my data.frame called `Lexicality.Centered`, where I renamed the variable. `Word` is 1 and `PseudoWord` is -1. I did the same with all binary fixed effects.

I also have a fixed effect with more than two levels. I created a new column where I recoded the names of the levels of these factor. One such factor, `Hemisphere`, has 3 levels: Right, Mid and left. Since I want to compare Left vs Right, I coded Left as -1, Right as 1 and Mid as 0. I thought this would result in a comparison of Left vs Right, ignoring the Mid level.

However, the summary of the model gives me two slopes for `Hemisphere`. This suggests the 0 level is also having a slope estimated:

```
Fixed effects:
                                         Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)                              -2.29676    0.34969  -6.568
Lexicality.Centered1                      0.27649    0.20105   1.375
Frequency.Centered1                      -0.02772    0.03777  -0.734
Hemisphere.Centered1                      0.04911    0.04344   1.130
Hemisphere.Centered2                     -0.06459    0.05045  -1.280
Region.Centered1                          0.01830    0.03705   0.494
Lexicality.Centered1:Frequency.Centered1  0.14925    0.03773   3.956
```

Am I interpreting this correctly? Is the Mid level, coded as 0, also being given a slope? If so, then what contrast should I use to compare left vs right, ignoring the mid level?

PS: I am aware I could specify the contrasts in the model, without having to create extra columns. I wish to do so however, because it allows me to keep track of the contrasts I am doing.

Comment: If you just change the factor levels R will still use treatment contrasts. Either you have to specify the contrasts you desire or you have to do the dummy encoding manually.

Comment: By specifying the contrasts, you mean using the contrasts() option? I thought I had done the dummy encoding manually. Lexicality has the dummy coding in Lexicality.Centered, for example. Or am I not understanding?

Comment: Yes, use the `contrasts` function or set the option. Dummy encoding means that if you have a factor with n levels you create n - 1 columns in the design matrix from it. That's not what you did. If you provide `lmer` with factor variables it does the dummy encoding for you (based on the provided or default contrasts).

Comment: You can use the `model.matrix` function to study the design matrix.